# How do I replace an entire array of subdocuments in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Here is an example document from my collection:

```
Books
[
   id: 1,
   links:
   [
     {text: "ABC", "url": "www.abc.com"},
     {text: "XYZ", "url": "www.xyz.com"}
   ]
]
```

I want to replace the links array in one update operation. Here is an example of how the above document should be modified:

```
Books
[
   id: 1,
   links:
   [
     {text: "XYZ", "url": "www.xyz.com"},
     {text: "efg", "url": "www.efg.com"},   <== NEW COPY OF THE ARRAY
     {text: "ijk", "url": "www.ijk.com"}
   ]
]
```

As you can see, the links array has been **replaced** (old data removed, and new data added).

I am having very hard time with the `Update.Set()` because it says it `MyLinks<>` cannot be mapped to a `BsonValue`

I've tried many different ways of achieving this, and all of them fail, including `.PushAllWrapped<WebLinkRoot>("links", myDoc.WebLinks)`.
Everything I've tried results in the new values being appended to the array, rather than the array being replaced.

As it seems MongoDB doesn't provide a simple method to replace an array of subdocument OR  a method like `.ClearArray()`, what is the best way for me to ensure the array is cleared before adding new elements in a single query?

Comment: You were on the right track with the [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator. That would replace the entire field with whatever you want, which is in your case a completely different array. Can't help right now with the exact C# syntax for that though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have to do something like this:

```csharp
var newArray = new BSONArray {
    new BSONDocument { { "text", "XYZ" }, { "url", "www.xyz.com" } },
    new BSONDocument { { "text", "efg" }, { "url", "www.efg.com" } },
    new BSONDocument { { "text", "ijk" }, { "url", "www.ijk.com" } }
};

var update = Update.Set( "links", newArray );

collection.Update( query, update );
```

Or whatever method you can to cast as a valid BSONValue.

So equivalent to shell:

```js
{ "links" : [ { "text" : "abc" } ] }

> db.collection.update(
      {},
      { $set: 
          { links: [ 
              { text: "xyz", url: "something" },
              { text: "zzz", url: "else" }
          ]}
      })

>db.collection.find({},{ _id: 0, links:1 }).pretty()

{ "links" : [
            {
                    "text" : "xyz",
                    "url" : "something"
            },
            {
                    "text" : "zzz",
                    "url" : "else"
            }
    ]
}
```

So that works.

You clearly need something else other than embedded code. But hopefully that puts you on the right track.

Comment: @kheya This is the equivalent of the $set operator from the shell syntax with a whole array containing documents. It should work. I don't expect you are actually doing this but something else with a class maybe?

Answer (score 11):

*I am here because I saw 5k views on this post, I'm adding some stuff may be it help other who looking for answer of above*

```
 db.collectionName.insertOne({
      'links': [
                 {
                     "text" : "XYZ",
                      "url" : "www.xyz.com"
                  }
        ]
  });
```

*now run this query which help to replace older data*

```
db.collectionName.update(
      {
        _id: ObjectId("your object Id")
      }, 
      {
        $set: 
         {
          'links':[ {
                     "text" : "XYZ1",
                     "url" : "www.xyz.com1"
                   } ]
         }
      });
```